# Problema com ponteiro e função recursiva

Tags: c, ponteiro, árvore-binária

O código é esse :

```
Node * search ( Node ** root, int mats ) {

    if ( ! ( * root ) ) {

        return NULL;

    } else {

        search ( & ( * root ) -> esq, mats );

        if ( ( * root ) -> person.mat == mats ) {

            return ( * root );

        }

        search ( & ( * root ) -> dir, mats );

    }

    // return NULL;

}
```

O problema é que o compilador aponta que está dando falha de segmentação ( Acredito que por causa do `return NULL` do final ), porém se eu remover o `return NULL` do final ele aponta que a função não está tendo retorno; então se deixo ele retornando `NULL` ele quebra o endereço que obtenho dentro do `else` ... como resolver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal:

```
Node * search( Node ** root, int mats )
{
    Node * n = *root;
    Node * e = NULL;

    /* verifica o fim da arvore */
    if( !n )
        return NULL;

    /* verifica o noh atual */
    if( n->person.mat == mats )
        return n;

    /* faz pesquisa na esquerda */
    e = search( &(n->esq), mats );

    /* se encontrou ocorrencia na esquerda... */
    if(e)
        return e;

    /* faz pesquisa na direita */
    return search( &(n->dir), mats );
}
```

Simplificando:

```
Node * search( Node * root, int mats )
{
    Node * e = NULL;

    /* verifica o fim da arvore */
    if( !root )
        return NULL;

    /* verifica o noh atual */
    if( root->person.mat == mats )
        return root;

    /* faz pesquisa na esquerda */
    e = search( root->esq, mats );

    /* se encontrou ocorrencia na esquerda... */
    if(e)
        return e;

    /* faz pesquisa na direita */
    return search( root->dir, mats );
}
```

Comment: Vlw, entendi oque estava fazendo de errado, o problema de não checar o primeiro nó estava na cara e ainda sim ... ( Além do problema que estava criando com o return; como extra usar as funções é melhor que ficar fazendo as comparações que estou fazendo tipo ! ( ) ) - Refatorado : Codeshare.io/5zEBz7

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você faz o `search(&(*root)->esq, mats);` e o `search(&(*root)->dir, mats);` e depois joga fora o valor de retorno da recursão, então a não ser que você calhe de procurar o valor que está no nó raiz, ele não vai conseguir retornar.

Você precisa de uma variável local de tipo `Node *`; no `else` você assinala o resultado de `search()` para essa variável e verifica se ela é nula. Se não for, retorne-a; senão, teste o valor do nó atual e retorne-o se for o correto; senão retorne o valor do segundo `search()`. Assim deve funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

O compilador não faz mágica - se você quer retornar o valor que a chamada recursiva à `search` achar para a função que chamou `search` pela primeira vez, coloque esse return explicitamente no código. Abaixo, está na penúltima linha:

```
Node * search ( Node ** root, int mats ) {
    if ( ! ( * root ) ) {
        return NULL;  
    }     

    if ( ( * root ) -> person.mat == mats ) {
            return ( * root );
        }
    return search ( & ( * root ) -> dir, mats );
}
```

Asoturas mudançs que fiz são: se a raiz for null, o restante da função não é executado - então não precisa estar dentro de um bloco `else`- isso diminui os níveis de `{ }`e identação e melhora a legibilidade.  Também parece que você tinha uma chamada a mais a `search` antes desse segundo `if`.

E como uma nota final, o *compilador*  nunca dá "segmentation fault" -  o sistema operacional dá um "segmentation fault" ao interromper o seu programa por que ele causou um acesso ilegal de memória.

Comment: A "chamada a mais" que ele tinha é a chamada feita à sub-árvore esquerda, e não pode ser removida. Por isso sugeri na minha resposta que pusesse o resultado daquela chamada numa variável local para verificar se ela trouxe a resposta.

Comment: Sim, preciso checar todos os nós.

Comment: Ah - desculpa - como não tinha a struct da árvore não fiquei reparando nos nomes dos membros  - fiz como se fosse uma lista ligada, e não uma árvore.